# Call a function within function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am facing problem in calling a function `demo1()` directly on button call.
Please See Code

```
var FormImageCrop = function (){
    var demo1 = function() {
        var jcrop_api;
        $('#demo1').Jcrop({
          onChange:   showCoords,
          aspectRatio: 4 / 3
        },function(){
          jcrop_api = this;
        jcrop_api.setSelect([0,0,3200,2400]);
        });
        $('#coords1').on('change','input',function(e){
          var x1 = $('#x11').val(),
              x2 = $('#x12').val(),
              y1 = $('#y11').val(),
              y2 = $('#y12').val();
          jcrop_api.setSelect([x1,y1,x2,y2]);
        });
        function showCoords(c)
        {
             $('#x11').val(c.x);
            $('#y11').val(c.y);
            $('#x12').val(c.x2);
            $('#y12').val(c.y2);
            $('#w1').val(c.w);
            $('#h1').val(c.h);
        };
    }
    return {
        init: function () {

            if (!jQuery().Jcrop) {;
                return;
            }

            demo1();
        }

    };
}();
```

i want to call this function on button click
like `<button onclick="demo1()">Click it</button>`

How can i call this function???

Comment: Why do you need to define the function within another function?

Comment: Define outside and call it twice - once from the function and once from the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to call function within the HTML is if the function itself is exposed on the global window object. I wouldn't necessarily do it like this but if you still want to call the function on the `onlick` property of the button you could do it like this:

```
 var FormImageCrop = function (){
        window.demo1 = function() {
            ...
            ...
        }
        return {
            init: function () {
                ...
                ...
                window.demo1();
            }

        };
}();
```

As i said, this is no ideal but it will work. A better alternative is to add an event listener to the button.

Hope it helps.

Comment: awesome here you can see http://jsfiddle.net/j1oLzdfg/
Now i want to pass a parameter like this 
`<button onclick="demo1('2')">Click it</button>`  
How can i do that??

Comment: Exactly as you did it, you function should then be like this: `function(val) {
            alert("Just check it: " + val);
        }`

Answer (score 4):

```
var myObject = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    fullName: function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
myObject.fullName();         // Will return "John Doe"
```

That is all.
You can read this whole tutorial from here
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

Or you can try this

```
var my_foo= function foo() {

    // do something

}
myfoo();
```

or

```
function bar() {

    // do something

}
bar();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also like that

```
var FormImageCrop = function (){
        window.demo1 = function(val) {
           alert(val);
        }
        return {
            init: function () {
                window.demo1();
            }
        };
}();
```

And button Link this

`<button onclick="demo1('abc')">Click It</button>`